# Android: Can aliases be used for styles (similar to layout aliases)?

Tags: android, xml, styles

Recently I discovered [layout aliases](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).

Does the same thing exist for styles?

For example, if my_page.xml uses normal_style, can I set up aliases so that when the device has an xlarge screen the xlarge_style is used instead (**without** me having to duplicate my_page.xml)?

Comment: Well, ideally, you would not have `normal_style` and `xlarge_style` in the first place. You'd have `my_style`, with two definitions, one in `res/values/` and one in `res/values-xlarge/`. That way, `my_page.xml` would refer to `my_style`, and Android would choose the right implementation of `my_style` based on screen size.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  So would I have two `styles.xml` files, one in `res/values/` an done in `res/values-xlarge`?

Comment: "So would I have two styles.xml files, one in res/values/ an done in res/values-xlarge?" -- yes. Each would define a style with the same name (e.g., `MyStyle`). When you reference that style elsewhere (e.g. from a widget), Android will choose the right one based on screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from @CommonsWare comments:

Have two `styles.xml` files, one under `res/values/` and one under `res/values-xlarge/`.  Each `styles.xml` file defines a style with the same name (eg: MyStyle).  Then Android chooses the right style based on screen size.

Comment: Actually this doesn't answer the question "Do aliases work for styles?". From my experiment I can say that NO they don't unfortunately (if written like this
`<item name="MyStyle" type="style">@style/OtherStyle</item>`)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
<style name="alias" parent="original"></style>
```

That should do make a new style that has a different name but the same properties as the original.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but that's not what I'm looking for :)  Thanks for taking the time to answer!